# Is it possible to run IntelliJ IDEA Inspections on TeamCity on several agents in parallel?

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity

Running [IntelliJ IDEA inspections on TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2022.04/inspections.html) takes too long for my project. For tests (e.g. JUnit), TeamCity can split tests into batches which are [run on multiple agents in parallel](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2022.04/parallel-tests.html).

As far as I can tell, this Build feature "Parallel tests" doesn't apply to build step "Inspections (IntelliJ IDEA)". Is there any way of running Inspections on TeamCity on multiple agents split into batches?

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-85108/Run-IntelliJ-IDEA-Inspections-on-TeamCity-on-several-agents-in-parallel) on your behalf. To ensure we capture your ideas effectively, we invite you to share any teamcity feature requests/bugs at [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW).